# How to relaunch updated table?

Tags: iphone

In my application, I fetch contactInfo from address book and this info populate on the tableView. when i check row using checkMark, then data delete and send on server. Left some data, which is unchecked.

Now After then I need unchecked data show me on tableView ,whenever i relaunch my application.

Thanx

Mishti

Answer (score 1):

Call [tableview reloadData] function to reload the table.

Comment: Hi, I used [tblVw reloadData] ,but it doesn't work for me according to my need . when i used [tblVw reloadData] then reloadData only for launching time, but after again relaunch time array show me previous all check and uncheck data.That is my big problem.

Comment: You need to move your fetch functionality to a separate function. After moving u can call his function and update your array and fire table reload command.